# GKE - GPU nvidia - cuda drivers dont work

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have setup a kubernetes node with a Nvidia Tesla k80 and followed [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus) to try to run a pytorch docker image with Nvidia drivers and CUDA drivers working.

I have managed to install the nvidia daemonsets and I can now see the following pods:

```
nvidia-driver-installer-gmvgt
nvidia-gpu-device-plugin-lmj84
```

The problem is that even while using the recommended image `nvidia/cuda:10.0-runtime-ubuntu18.04` I still can't find the Nvidia drivers inside my pod:

```
root@pod-name-5f6f776c77-87qgq:/app# ls /usr/local/
bin  cuda  cuda-10.0  etc  games  include  lib  man  sbin  share  src
```

But the tutorial mentions:

> CUDA libraries and debug utilities are made available inside the container at `/usr/local/nvidia/lib64` and `/usr/local/nvidia/bin`, respectively.

I have also tried to test if CUDA was working through `torch.cuda.is_available()` but I get False as a return value.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58766003/2777965

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i finally made it work.

It is mandatory set a ressource limit to access the nvidia driver, which is weird considering either way my pod was on the right node with the nvidia drivers installed..